# injection $(\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1,2\})\to\ (\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

It is also possible to find a surjection in the other direction - I am trying to prove the cardinality of $$\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1,2\}$$ is less than or equal to $$\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$$

Comment: What is your question? Also what should $\Bbb N\to\{0,1,2\}$ denote? A function? A set of functions?

Comment: I am asking for help - I don't know how to find a function like this.

Comment: The set of all functions from the natural numbers to {0,1,2}

Comment: @StefanMesken Of course! I thought about $\{0,1\}\to\Bbb N$. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f \colon \mathbb N \to \{0,1,2\}$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ let
$$
f^*(3n) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if } f(n) = 0 \\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
f^*(3n+1) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if } f(n) = 1 \\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
f^*(3n+2) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if } f(n) = 2 \\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\pi \colon (\mathbb N \to \{0,1,2\}) \to (\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}), \ f \mapsto f^*
$$
is an injection.

Comment: How is it an injection? For example, suppose f1, f2 from N to {0,1,2}. Let's say they are the same function except for n=3 f1 returns 1 and f2 returns 2. isn't f* the same in this case?

Comment: In this case $f_1^*(10) =1$ and $f_2^*(10) = 0$, so that $f_1^* \neq f_2^*$. And the reasoning behind this example generalizes to show that $\pi$ is in fact an injection.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Write a function $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1,2\}$ as a string of digits $0,1,2$. Now encode this string in binary, mapping $0 \mapsto 00$, $1 \mapsto 01$, $2 \mapsto 10$. This gives a function $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ from which you can recover the original function.

Comment: How can I write a function as a string?

Comment: Just write $f_0 f_1 f_2 \cdots$

Answer (score 2):

For a sequence $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1, 2\}$ define a sequence mapping the digits as $0 \mapsto 1$, $1 \mapsto 10$, $2 \mapsto 100$.

For example:

$$(1,2,1,0,2, \ldots ) \mapsto (1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0, \ldots)$$

This map is clearly injective since the number of zeros after each $1$ determines which was the digit of the original sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the functions of $\mathbb N \to \{0, 1, 2\}$ into $\mathbb N \to \{0, 1\}$ as follows:

given a function $f : \mathbb N \to \{0, 1, 2\}$,

- let $g(2n) = f(n)$ if $f(n) \in \{0, 1\}$, and $g(2n) = 0$ otherwise,
- and let $g(2n+1) = 1$ if $f(n) = 2$, and $g(2n+1) = 0$ otherwise.